# Parse .java file and analyze its AST

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Im looking for a parser that could parse .java file and create some object, which should held informations about this file's methods, attributes. classes, interfaces, methods parameters and annotations.

Do you know any?

I found https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/, but im not sure if it can handle annotations, which are important for me..

any advice?

thanks

Comment: hmmm why not use reflection to retrieve this information?

Comment: If you're not sure if it can handle annotations, it would be preferable it you did some more research prior to posting here...

Comment: There are many parsers available for Java code, each with its own intended purpose and advantages/disadvantages. Based on the amount of detail in the original post, 1) there's no way to determine what would be appropriate for your case and 2) these parsers are *highly* non-trivial to use, and there's no indication that you've researched this space enough to be able to actually use one that gets suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the standard [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javac/)? I know it was discussed within the latest Java Magazine issue -- for some source samples, [see here](https://java.net/projects/java-magazine/downloads/directory/MarchApril2013).

Comment: This + Java Annotation Processors should be enough for all code generation needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Java Grammar (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) and use a parser generator (for example YACC) or Scala ParserCombinators to generate an AST. In this grammar, annotations are contained.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [JavaParser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser) to parse java Code, and yes - it can handle annotations, for example - getting method's annotations:

```
List<AnnotationExpr> annotations = method.getAnnotations();
```

Adding annotations (by name) to a method:

`annotations.add(new NormalAnnotationExpr( ASTHelper.createNameExpr("Override"), null));`